# Inherited entity Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have this model

```
Class1
    data1
    data2 (one to many relation)

Class2 extends Class1
    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Class3", mappedBy="data4")
     */
    data3

Class3
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Class2")
     */
    data4
```

I found two solution to use inherited classes with doctrine.
the first one is to use [mapped super class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses).
But I have a problem, MappedSuperClass can't have oneToMany relation

The second one is [the table inherence](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) 
But in this case I can't create empty classes (for exemple my class2)

Do you have a solution use my model with doctrine ?

Comment: You can use table inheritance and make class2 allow null (nullable=true)

Comment: Yes, this is what I done but I create a useless field